# How can I pass the value of a selected option of a dropdown box(which is in a form) from html to ts file, without submitting the form in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm new to angular. The following code section carries a dropdown box which is in a form. I'm trying to pass 'serial' from HTML file to ts file. I'm trying to do this without submitting the form. However, I'm unsuccessful till now. What can I do to pass 'serial' from HTML to ts file without submitting the form?

```
                            <mat-option>All</mat-option>
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let userRole of serialList">
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let serial of userRole.SerialOneList">
                                    <mat-option [value]="serial">
                                        {{serial}}
                                    </mat-option>
                               </ng-container>

                            </ng-container>

                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error>Serial Number is required!</mat-error>

                    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="variableNameInTs" will hold the actual value of select in component's variableNameInTs. also you can change selected value from component by changing value of that variable. For examples check 2way binding.

Comment: another way is by using form builder. that's need more studying of the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material select [API](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) provides `selectionChange` emitter that you could bind an handler to.

Try the following

**Template**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  ...
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option>All</mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let userRole of serialList">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let serial of userRole.SerialOneList">
        <mat-option [value]="serial">
          {{serial}}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error>Serial Number is required!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Controller**

```js
import { MatSelectChange } from "@angular/material/select";

onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
  console.log(event.value);
}
```